# Angular @Input, binding object to same object but with different property names

Tags: angular

I read in the documentation that you can change the property name like the following: `@Input('account-id') id: string;`

But is there a way to change the property name in an object, to different names?

I have a reusable radio button component that takes an object that I want to look like the following:

```
export class ICustomRadioButton {
    name: string;
    color: string;
    rank: number;
 }

 // ...

 @Input('buttons') radioButtons: ICustomRadioButton;
```

But I would like the objects that I pass into the radio button component to look like the following:

```
Sample1: {levelName: 'One', levelColor: #ffffff, levelRank: 2}
Sample2: {cutomerName: 'Alfa', cutomerColor: #ffffff, cutomerRank: 4}

<app-custom-radio-group [buttons]='customerInfo' (buttonPicked)='buttonPicked($event)'></app-custom-radio-group>
```

So the object that gets passed in will always have the same structure, but the names should change so that I can have custom property names outside of my component, but have generic property names inside my component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to map the passed model to your internal model.

First of all you'd have to use a property instead of a class variable (at least the setter):

```
// since this is plural, you probably want an array instead?
private _buttonsModel: ICustomRadioButton = {};

// we'll use "any" type, since we don't know the property names
private _radioButtons: any;

get radioButtons(): any {
    return this._radioButtons;
}

@Input('buttons')
set radioButtons(value: any) {
    this._radioButtons = value;

    // mapping: you got different solutions here, for example Object.keys etc.
    // for-in loops through all properties
    for (const property in value) {
        // now compare the property names to the ones you're looking for
        if (property.endsWith('Name') { this._buttonsModel.name = value[property]; }
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the monstrosity that I have come up with while waiting for the answer. A shame there is not something more simple. Seeing as this is indeed an answer to my question, I will wait a little while to see if there is another solution and then mark it as correct - thanks!

Comment: well yes, it's a monstrosity XD but there's no way to convert a model to another one without mapping of some kind. you'd have to map before passing it to your component or hide the mapping in there. another way would be to allow for multiple types, but then you'd have to check what type you got inside the setter. another way would be to change the models to inherit from ICustomRadioButton and have getters/setters that modify the base properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can make more confortable (but equal of montruosity)

```
_radioButtons:any={"Name"."",Color:"",Rank:""} //<--define a model
@Input('buttons')
set radioButtons(value: any) {
    for (let property in this.model)
    {
      //You can use x.indexOf(property)>=0 or x.endWidth(property)
      let field=Object.keys(value).find(x=>x.indexOf(property)>=0);
      this._radioButtons[property]=field?value[field]:null
    }
}
```